# Modal UIViewController can't receive NSNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a modal UIViewController:

```
let rVC = RecoveryViewController()
rVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(rVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In `viewDownload` of this ViewController I have a function `user.checkUserData()` that would send NSNotifications when the job is done.

And, of course, observers for any of these notifications:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RecoveryViewController.userVIP), name: userDataIsHere, object: nil)
```

But it seems that my modal ViewController is not able to receive any notifications, because nothing is happening. At the same time if I tried to add such observer to the parent UIViewController (non-modal), it'd work like a charm (actually, I checked).

My notifications are quite simple, and

```
let userDataIsHere = Notification.Name("userDataIsHere")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: userDataIsHere, object: nil)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you adding the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RecoveryViewController.userVIP), name: userDataIsHere, object: nil)`. Why not adding it directly in your controller in the init method ?

Comment: in `viewDownload`, right after `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: `RecoveryViewController.userVIP` references a class method. Selectors need to reference an instance method, e.g. `self.userVIP` or just `userVIP`

Comment: Do you mean `viewDidLoad` by `viewDownload`? `viewDidLoad` is a method of `UIViewController` and should be named as such when you are implementing it. `viewDownload` has no meaning if you are not calling it somewhere else in your code explicitly.

Comment: yes, of course, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let userDataIsHere = Notification.Name("userDataIsHere")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modalPopUp), name: userDataIsHere, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func modalPopUp() {
        let rVC = RecoveryViewController()
        rVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        self.present(rVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you completed below things:

```
1) Notification Registered before use
2) Notification identifier must be same.
```

Here is my code for notification:

1) Registered Notification in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier")
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourFunctionName), name: notificationName, object: nil)

@objc func yourFunctionName(notification: NSNotification){
    //do stuff
    print("Called..")
}
```

2) Post notification when you required:

```
    // Post notification
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
```